# without page load how to get response using asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I need a coding to get response from my desktop application to my web page using asp.net

I send a request  from my recharge.aspx page to desktop application.

http://122.172.208.202/MARSrequest/?operator=RA&number=9900122334&amount=100&reqref=A0000001

so my desktop application  get the request and perform the task and send the response to other page that is responseparser.aspx

the response like

http://www.abc.com/responseparser.aspx?ref=10293&number=9894380156&amount=100&status=SUCCESS&transid=547965399 &simbal=1000

so how to get response with out loading the responseparser page it is possible or any other idea to get the response.

my doubt is without loading a page can  able to perform some operation like insert a record or create text file using asp.net

Comment: You need to do better explaining what is it you want to achieve and what the problem is.

Comment: can you give a little more background as to what you're trying to do. If you don't want to execute the method when a page loads, when DO you want the method to execute? There are myriads of different options, but if you don't tell us when this is supposed to run, then we can't really help you.

Comment: pps: your `Example of request` is invalid because it's on your localhost.

Comment: this is example link not for original

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*You appear to have asked this question several times in several different ways. This is not an acceptable way of using StackOverflow. If your original question is not getting the answer(s) your looking for, please consider editing and revising your question. Please consider commenting on your questions and taking the advice of other commenters.*

To answer your question. I think you're looking to execute some sort of `Web Service` instead of loading a page. Does this sound right?

If so, I'd suggest either using one of the following

- a generic [HttpHandler](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4643/implementing-http-handlers-in-aspnet/) (more info in this [forum post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1011421.aspx/1?What%20is%20HTTPModule%20and%20HttpHandler))
- a [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx) application that can manage your service layer.
- an [MVC Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd943053.aspx) that manages the requests (this is my personal favorite - I build these completely without Views and simply return JSON for all of my `{success: true/false}`.)

---

**In short, the quickest way I can think of to do this would be to use the FIRST option (`HttpHandler`) and change your request to the following**

http://localhost/responsepage.ashx?number=9894380156&amount=10&status=success

*Notice the `ashx` extension on the response page. It's no longer a web page but a web handler... you'll want to do some research in order to get a handle on it.*

Comment: ps: I don't fully know your application but this doesn't seem right `&status=success` - shouldn't the status be returned by the `responsepage`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this if this works same for desktop applications but maybe it works with

```
protected void YourThing()
{

Refresh();

}

protected void Refresh()

{
Response.redirect(Request.Rawurl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure but try

```
for(!Page.IsPostback)
{
do stuf here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WebService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68zt3df9%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) or [HttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228090%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

I would prefer WebService (parser.asmx):

```
namespace Test.Service
{
  [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
  [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
  [ToolboxItem(false)]
  public class WebService1 : WebService
  {
    [WebMethod]
    public void Parse(string @ref, long number, double amount, string status, int transid, int simbal)
    {
      // some code
    }
  }
}
```

POST-request example:

```
POST /{path}/Parser.asmx/Parse HTTP/1.1
Host: ***
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: ***

ref=string&number=string&amount=string&status=string&transid=string&simbal=string
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily port your ASP code using the [`SqlClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.aspx) classes.
Most suitable variant for you is [`SqlCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) with [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) method:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
           connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    command.Connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. i know the concept of ado.net. i need a help that is without page load how to perform some task? the above asp to  coding the page can't be load just i request the page that time one record is inserted. ok whether you understand my problem?

Answer (score 0):

In that case, I usually put whatever appropriate ADO.NET code into page_load but since you want to do it before page loading, why don't you use "page_init"? For example, put following code into code-behind

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //your code is here
}
```

Comment: i dnt want to go the page event because the user can't see the page they just click the button from one page like recharge.aspx that time one request go to this page.

Comment: I think he's looking for an HttpHandler.